# How to convert MySQL to PostgreSQL and add timezone conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, database-migration, postgresql-9.3

I want to display all courses that have been accessed in the last 2 years, who accessed it last and when.

This MySQL query lists when each course was last accessed and by who. I'm converting this query to PostgreSQL 9.3.22. I haven't had much exposure to Postgres, which is proving very difficult. I also need to convert the epoch date to a different time zone, as the PostgreSQL database location is not in my timezone. Edit: `timecreated` in both databases is stored as epoch (e.g. `1612399773`)

```sql
select
    userid 'lastaccesseduserid',
    courseid,
    contextid,
    from_unixtime(max(timecreated), '%D %M %Y') 'lastaccesseddate'
from mdl_logstore_standard_log
where timecreated >= unix_timestamp(date_sub(now(), interval 2 year))
group by courseid
```

This lists the output as such:

```
| lastaccesseduserid | courseid | contextid | lastaccesseddate  |
|--------------------|----------|-----------|-------------------|
| 45                 | 6581     | 68435     | 22nd January 2021 |
| 256676             | 32       | 4664      | 19th August 2019  |
etc.
```

My efforts at converting to PostgreSQL:

```sql
select
    distinct ON (courseid) courseid,
    contextid,
    to_timestamp(max(timecreated))::timestamptz::date at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' "last accessed date",
    userid
from mdl_logstore_standard_log
where timecreated >= extract(epoch from now()- interval '2 year')
group by courseid
-- error: column userid, contextid must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

None of these columns is the Primary Key (`id` is, as per [here](https://moodleschema.zoola.io/tables/logstore_standard_log.html)). Grouping by `id` is bad, as it will list every entry in the log table instead. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.6?

Comment: Close! MySQL 5.7

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres is correct, that query is not valid SQL.

> SQL-92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause.

You can't `group by courseid` and `select courseid, contextid, userid` because each `courseid` might have many rows with different contextids and userids. You either need to `group by courseid, contextid, userid` or you need to [tell the database how you want those columns aggregated](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) like with `sum` or `string_agg`.

I can't tell you which is correct, but the original never really worked. MySQL is just choosing one value at random for you.

> In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want

MySQL allowed some unwise SQL "extensions" which later versions turned them off by default. This particular one is controlled by [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) which MySQL 5.7 and up wisely turn on by default. Your database either turned it off, or is so old that it was not the default.

See [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) for more.

I would suggest first enabling `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and fixing the queries in MySQL. Then port to Postgres.

MySQL has many such non-standard features. PostgreSQL is much more standards compliant. It will be a struggle to both convert to standard SQL and PostgreSQL. I would suggest doing them one at a time. First, convert to standard SQL by turning on [ANSI and TRADITITONAL SQL modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-important) and fix the resulting issues in MySQL. Then try converting the now more standard SQL to PostgreSQL. These SQL modes are collections of MySQL server configs, like `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, and can be turned on and fixed one at a time.

---

Note that PostgreSQL 9.3.22 end-of-lifed two years ago. It would be silly to do all that work to change databases only to use an obsolete version. Consider an upgrade.

Storing times as Unix epochs is awkward and unnecessary. If at all possible, consider converting to [`timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) while migrating your data. If you intend to also store the time zone, use `timestamp with zone`.

Comment: In regards to your `group by courseid` comment - I should clarify a couple of things about the Moodle platform. `courseid` and `contextid have a N-1 relationship (a course exists in 1 context, a context has many courses). Unfortunately, I'm running this query via an ad-hoc reporting Moodle addon and not directly via the database (I'm not the DBA), meaning I don't have DB access to alter settings. Kinda writing this with both hands tied, I know. 

Also can't change the epoch decision - that's done by Moodle. Changing this requires an entire re-write of the application. Trust me, not worth it.

Comment: I'm no db developer by any stretch - I'm learning as I go. What should the query be? I don't want the `userid` and `contextid` columns aggregated - just list those values for the `max(timecreated)` value.

Comment: Switching from MySQL, particularly before MySQL 8, to anything else is a challenge even for an experienced DBA. Doing it with both hands tied will be even harder. Consider if this is necessary, maybe explain why you're doing it? Showing the full schema of `mdl_logstore_standard_log` would help. `show create table mdl_logstore_standard_log`. "*I don't want the userid and contextid columns aggregated*" You don't have a choice. You must either aggregate them, include them in the group by, or drop them from the select. Perhaps explain the purpose of the query.

Comment: The last hyperlink in my OP is the schema for the table. I can't run the `show` command, as the add-in prevents using functions that edit or create data in the database - it's designed to execute queries that only read the data. See [here](https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Configurable_reports#Overview) for more info. 

The query's purpose is to list all courses that have been accessed within the last 2 years, list the user that last accessed it and when.

Comment: @Zectzozda "*The query's purpose is to list all courses that have been accessed within the last 2 years, list the user that last accessed it and when.*" Ok, put that in your question, please. It does not currently do that because of how MySQL is fudging the group by. And what's to be done with the contextid?

Comment: Once this query is working, I'll expand it to include the user's role and some other information from joining other tables. `contextid` also has meaning to the users that will run this report, hence displaying it. e.g. `join mdl_role_assignments ra on ra.roleid = contextid`. Will edit the question in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify  what your intention is, but it seems you want to get the latest `timecreated` for each courseid.

This does not need a GROUP BY in Postgres, only `distinct on ()`. Which has the added benefit that you can include any column you want without being limited by the `GROUP BY` rules. This only works however if you want one row per `courseid` (and that should be the "earliest" or "latest"). For other requirements (e.g. "the three latest") window functions are a better fit.

`to_timestamp()` already returns a `timestamptz` so the cast is unnecessary. If you want to remove the time part (which is what the `::date` cast will do) I think that should be done *after* you adjusted the time zone. But then adjusting the time zone seems rather futile if you don't care about the time.

```
select distinct ON (courseid) 
        courseid,
        contextid,
        to_timestamp(timecreated) at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' "last accessed date",
    userid
from mdl_logstore_standard_log
where to_timestamp(timecreated) >= current_timestamp - interval '2 year'
group by courseid, 3 DESC
```

You should also use a real `timestamp` value in the WHERE clause because the duration of "2 years" might be different depending on the actual year. Comparing epochs won't take that into account.

You might want to think of changing the column to a proper `timestamptz` column completely in the long run.

Instead of referencing the column index in (`3`) in the order by, you can also repeat the whole expression: `order by courseid, to_timestamp(timecreated) at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' DESC`

---

And you **really** shouldn't be using Postgres 9.3 - especially not for a new installation. There is no reason to not use the latest version (which is 13 as of 2021-02-04). If this is an existing (old) installation, upgrade as soon as possible. [Upgrading from 9.3.22 to 13.1 gives you 2.7 years worth of fixes (2278 of them)](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.3.22&to=13.1)